# Hey guys, im writing a old mcdonald program using filesin python3, i need it to loop the lines in the correct order

Tags: python-3.x, file

i need to use these lists to display the song old macdonald in the correct order, but im not sure how to get the noise part of the loop to iterate just one line at a time?
any help would be greatly appreciated

```
f=open('livestock.txt','w')
print('cows',file=f)
print('sheep',file=f)
print('ducks',file=f)
print('horses',file=f)
print('chickens',file=f)
f.close()
f=open('noises.txt','w')
print('moo!',file=f)
print('Ba!',file=f)
print('quack!',file=f)
print('neigh!',file=f)
print('cluck!',file=f)
f.close()


f=open('livestock.txt','r')
g=open("noises.txt")


for animals in f:
    animals=animals.strip('\n')
    print("old macd had a farm E I EI O. ")
    print('and on that farm he had some ', animals)
    print("E I EI O")
    for noise in g:
        print("with a ",noise,noise,"here and a ",noise,noise,"there, here a ",noise,'there a',noise,"everywhere a", noise, noise)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple option is to use the file object's `readline` method to read one single line from the file: `noise_line = g.readline()`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful URL's for your question :
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/readline.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm

Adding to sammy's note, readline() reads entire line from file. It takes strings and output is your line. 
If you need to specify size of the argument (which should be a positive number) then maxi um byte count maybe returned.

Change your access to "rw+" instead of "w".

```
f = open('livestock.txt', 'rw+')
print "livestock.txt" , f.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much! this is what i finished with

```
f=open('livestock.txt','w')
print('cows',file=f)
print('sheep',file=f)
print('ducks',file=f)
print('horses',file=f)
print('chickens',file=f)
f.close()
f=open('noises.txt','w')
print('moo!',file=f)
print('Ba!',file=f)
print('quack!',file=f)
print('neigh!',file=f)
print('cluck!',file=f)
f.close()


f=open('livestock.txt','r')
g=open("noises.txt",'r')


for animal in f:
    animal=animal.strip('\n')
    f=g.readline()
    f=f.strip("\n")
    print("old macd had a farm, E I EI O. ")
    print('and on that farm he had some ', animal)
    print("E I EI O")
    print("with a ",f,f,"here and a ",f,f,"there, here a ",f,'there a',f,"everywhere a", f,f)
    print()
```

Comment: Wait, did you give the name `f` to the file object AND to the line that you read from the file? That's definitely not a good thing. :) Also, you should try to use more expressive names than "f" and similar.

Comment: i did too :(    poor planning on my behalf

Answer (score 0):

You mention

> i need to use these lists to display the song old macdonald in the correct order

So i am not sure if your question really has a requirement for writing and reading from files or if you do just want to use the python builtin type of `list`. If you do want to use lists then you can achieve it with

```py
animals = ['cows', 'sheep', 'ducks', 'horses', 'chickens']
noises = ['moo!', 'Ba!', 'quack!', 'neigh!', 'cluck!']
farm = zip(animals, noises)
for animal, noise in farm:
    print("old macd had a farm E I EI O. ")
    print(f'and on that farm he had some {animal}')
    print("E I EI O")
    print(f"with a {noise} {noise} here and a {noise} {noise} there, here a {noise}, there a {noise}, everywhere a {noise} {noise}")
```